# POST files uploading - multipart/form-data + UTF bug in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, http, uploading, litespeed

When I try to upload files using HTTP post with header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----NPRequestBoundary-----` everything works as expected but trying to use `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----NPRequestBoundary-----; charset=UTF-8` cause completely blank $_FILES array.
Is it a problem with PHP or web server? As I know this form of `Content-Type` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug was fixed in SVN rev. #316373 (5.3.9 release covers it).

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data`, this means it is built up from parts, and every part can have its own `Content-Type`. The charset parameter is only used with `text/plain` content-type. So it is meanless with a `multipart/form-data` content-type.

Comment: You're wrong I think - what about filenames encoding? Adding charset directly to `Content-Type` will take care about it. The worst thing in all this is that I can not modify the client application.

Answer (score 0):

I've found dirty workaround for this problem. For me it's ofc temporary bcs it doesn't work under litespeed (I used reverse proxy to apache to avoid this problem).
    `<Location "/upload.php">`
    `RequestHeader set Content-Type "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----NPRequestBoundary-----"`
      `</Location>`

It will force webserver to replace content-type header. For now I'm sure - this is a PHP bug (someone assumed that charset will occur before `boundary=`)